# Select 'long' data type with formatted output using Substring or Right/Left

Tags: sql-server, regex

My select statement returns a list of long values which cannot be used as the expression in substring.
The values returned by my query are 9 or 10 digits long. If it is 9 digits long for example 123456789 I want the result like 0-123-456-789 else in case of 10 digits like 3123456789 I want it as 3-123-456-789.

Is there any function like '**right**' or '**left**' which can be used similar to the **substring** i.e. with 3 parameters where I can mention the starting point.

Just point me to the right direction like the name of the function or the correct way to use formatting functions in a select statement.

Comment: I would recommend leaving formatting to the front end. If you MUST do this in sql you should look at STUFF although it is not entirely clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I need the result of my query to be in this format just for some testing purpose. A different application, not connected to this db, takes input in this format and I didn't want to add '-' to every result before feeding it to that application and was wondering if there was an easier way to do it through SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`Stuff`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms188043.aspx) and [**`Right`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms177532.aspx) string function to do this.

```
DECLARE @digits Bigint=3123456789

SELECT Stuff(Stuff(Stuff(RIGHT('0'+ convert(varchar(10),@digits),10),2,0, '-'),6,0, '-'),10,0,'-')
```

**Result:** `3-123-456-789`

Comment: My select statement returns only 1 column with more than 100 records. Some records may contain 9 digits where I would want to append 0 in the beginning like 0-123-456-789 while some others may be 10 digits and would not need any appending for example 2-874-645-256 or 9-634-107-360. I understand that in the above query instead of '123456789' I can put in my field name, but it would still append '0' to all records. Is there a way around it ?

Comment: @Xion no it won't. I have updated my answer now am passing 10 digit value check the answer. Just replace `@digits` with your column name

Comment: My datatype is long so the only thing missing from the above query was the casting part. I realized this through @gvee's answer. So the query becomes
`Select Stuff(Stuff(Stuff(RIGHT('0'+ Cast(MyLongColumn As varchar(10)),10),2,0, '-'),6,0, '-'),10,0,'-')` 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**IMPORTANT:** formatting should be left to your presentation layer, and not your database.

That being said, if you're determined to format the values then you're going to have to convert them to strings first!

```
SELECT your_field As original_value
     , Cast(your_field As varchar(10)) As stringified
     , '0000000000' + Cast(your_field As varchar(10)) As pad_with_zeroes
     , Right('0000000000' + Cast(your_field As varchar(10)), 10) As trim_to_ten_characters
FROM   your_table
```

Your formatting then becomes easy:

```
SELECT original_value
     , trim_to_ten_characters
     , SubString(trim_to_ten_characters, 1, 1)
     + '-'
     , SubString(trim_to_ten_characters, 2, 3)
     + '-'
     , SubString(trim_to_ten_characters, 5, 2)
     + '-'
     , SubString(trim_to_ten_characters, 8, 3) As formatified
     , Stuff(Stuff(Stuff(trim_to_ten_characters, 8, 0, '-'), 5, 0, '-'), 2, 0, '-') As alternative_method
FROM   (
        <that query from above>
       ) As aliased_query
```